# How surefire-plugin can be used more effectively to generate reports for JUnits

Tags: java, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to know what else we can do with surefire-plugin apart from generating reports in .xml files. Like when we combine it with site-plugin, we get nicely designed HTML page. What else we can do or add along with surefire-plugin so we can get more out of it.

Comment: Have you looked at the [official page](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/index.html)?

Comment: Yes, I have seen it entirely.

Comment: "so we can get more out of it" => What exactly do you want? This is a bit vague.

Comment: And ... As you get an XML output, you can always do an XSLT to produce whatever you want.